# SQL error in SQL server using REPLACE statement

Tags: sql-server, session, replace

I have the following query:

```
REPLACE sessions (session_id,session_data,expires) VALUES('pcal586o43604g0vpu5j22', 'id|i:111;user|N;s:9:\\\"admin\\\";admin_page|s:16:\"/control/\";', 1317934461)
```

Which works fine with mysql but when using SQL SERVER it throws this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'session_id'.

Can anyone tell me anything that might be wrong with this query?

Comment: Would I have to look up to see if it exists already and then either update or insert based on this. Is that the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server has no equivalent to MySQL's [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html). You'd have to code the functionality manually.

Answer (score 2):

There is no command `REPLACE` in SQL Server to replace values in a table.... you need to use a standard SQL UPDATE statement instead:

```
UPDATE dbo.sessions 
SET session_id = 'pcal586o43604g0vpu5j22',
      session_data = 'id|i:111;user|N;s:9:\\\"admin\\\";admin_page|s:16:\"/control/\";',
      expires = 1317934461
WHERE .... (some condition here - otherwise you update ALL rows!)
```

T-SQL's `REPLACE` function is a string function to replace a given substring inside another string with a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

In TSQL, [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) is a string function, rather than a set-based operation.

In MySQL, [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) is a MySQL extension to the SQL standard. It either inserts, or deletes and inserts.